# Two well orders on an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have two well orders $\preceq_1, \preceq_2$ on an uncountable set $X$.

Why would there be a set $Y\subseteq X$ such that $Y\restriction_{\preceq_1} = Y\restriction_{\preceq_2}$ and Y is uncountable?

I'm trying and trying to come up with a proof but I don't see why that would be true at all.

Say, I want to do it by induction. Then sure, I can choose two elements of $X$ such that they are in the same relation both with respect to $\preceq_1$ and $\preceq_2$. But why can I find a third element like this? Or $n$-th? Or $\gamma$-th... Perhaps there are no such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there exists $X_1\subset X$ so that $(X_1,\le_1)$ is isomorphic to $\omega_1$. Now there exists $X_2\subset X_1$ so $(X_2,\le_2)$ is isomorphic to $\omega_1$. And hence $(X_2,\le_1)$ is also isomorphic to $\omega_1$, since any uncountable subset of $\omega_1$ is isomorphic to $\omega_1$.

Say $Y$ is a *maximal* subset of $X_2$ such that the two orders agree on $Y$. Say $Z$ is the set of all $z\in X_2$ such that $z\le_1 y$ for some $y\in Y$. If $Y$ is countable then $Z$ is countable. So there exists $x\in X_2$ such that $x\notin Z$ and also $x>_2y$ for all $y\in Y$, so $Y$ was not maximal after all.

Comment: Wow, that's a super cool proof!

Comment: @Jules And not only that, I _think_ the latest version is actually right.

Comment: Is it clear that a maximal $Y$ exists? We can get it from Zorn's lemma, but it seems to be reasonable to expect not to need choice because everything is assumed to be well-orderable from the beginning. It may be better to start by setting $Y=\varnothing$ and then repeatedly (by transfinite induction over $\omega_1$) adding the $\le_1$-smallest element of $X$ that is larger than all elements already in $Y$ according to both $\le_1$ and $\le_2$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, what I had in mind was using Zorn's lemma. I simply have a bad attitude, not being concerned about whether I'm using AC. Yes, here what you suggest is better...

Comment: I don't see how Y countable implies Z countable.

Comment: @user254665 The reason for the preliminary finagling is so that $Y$ countable will imply $Z$ countable. Since $(X_2,\le_1)$ is isomorphic to $\omega_1$ every element has at most countably many predecessors.

Comment: I overlooked the fact that $ X_2\subset X_1 $, which makes it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=\big\{\{x,y\}\in[X]^2:\preceq_1\text{ and }\preceq_2\text{ agree on }x\text{ and }y\big\}$, and let $B=[X]^2\setminus A$. By the [Dushnik-Miller theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463870/dushnik-miller-proof) either

1. there is an uncountable $Y\subseteq X$ such that $[Y]^2\subseteq A$, or
2. there is an infinite $Y\subseteq X$ such that $[Y]^2\subseteq B$.

Use the fact that $\preceq_1$ and $\preceq_2$ are well-orders to show that the second alternative is impossible.

Comment: And that's an awesome proof as well!

Comment: Is it possible to replace the theorem you quote by the (infinite) Ramsey Theorem?

Comment: @dav11: I don’t see how: it only guarantees you an infinite set on which the orders agree.

Comment: Oh my, I praised this answer so much and now I got lost and don't know why there can't be no countable set which every two elements are differerent with respect to $\preceq_{1,2}$... Actually I think this was my issue from the beginning

Comment: @Jules: Suppose that there is such an infinite set. It must contain a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ that is strictly increasing with respect to $\preceq_1$. But then it’s strictly decreasing with respect to $\preceq_2$, which is impossible, since $\preceq_2$ is a well-order.

Comment: Yup, simple, thank you very, very much!

Comment: @Jules: You’re welcome!